# Split a value with delimiter length 3 '|||'

Tags: sql, regex, plsql

I have a PLSQL code to fetch data from a table with 30 rows out of which  10 columns are with delimiter of length 3 and I need to convert 1 row into multiple rows based on number of fields in those 10 columns.

So I am loading all Data into 1 temp table , and on temp table I am calling a cursor which will split data and insert multiple rows into main table.

Inside cursor I am using `regexp_substr` to split the Value and regular expression used by me is `[^\\|]+{3}` , I am not getting actual Values after splitting.

Sample data used for test case is

```
100|||200||300|||400||||0
```

After splitting I should get values as below

```
100, 200||300 , 400 , |0
```

But what I am getting is

```
100 , 200, 300 ,400, 0
```

Can any one suggest me the proper way to do it?

Waiting for reply!
Thanks

Comment: you need  100||20|||300|||400 to 
100-1 row
200-2 row
300-3 row ?

Comment: declare
cursor cdr is select * from TEMP_TABLE;
begin
  for b_new in cdr loop
             for i in 0..regexp_count(b_new.CHARGE,'[~]')  loop
                insert into MAIN_TABLE  (col1,col2,col3 etc ... )
                     values (regexp_substr(b_new.col1, '[^~]+', 1, i),'0'),b_new.col2,regexp_substr(b_new.col3, '[^~]+', 1, i), etc );
             end loop;
  end loop;
end;



above Code works well with delimiter length =1 , How to make it work for ||| as delimiter ?

Comment: sample table with 3 column 

A B C 
1 2||2  3 . 
 
 Then I need output to be 
1 2 3 - row 1 and 
1 2 3 - row 2

Comment: Use [Replace](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions153.htm#SQLRF00697)  to replace the '|||' with something fancy like '~'.

Comment: Ya i used the same but can i do replace on an entire row selected ???

I mean etire Row in cursor ? because if i work on each column it will slow down my process as it works on crores of records per hour .

Here b_new will be the entire row in above example

Answer (score 2):

Try this. Hope it helps.

```
SELECT REPLACE('100|||200||300|||400||||0','|||',',') OUTPUT FROM DUAL;

----------------------------OUTPUT---------------------------------------------

OUTPUT

100,200||300,400,|0
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

Regex `(\|*\d.*?)\|{3}|(\|*\d$)` captures what you're after [here](https://regex101.com/r/fN7iD4/2).

Comment: Yeah regular expression worked for me , Thank You so much :-)

Comment: In my splitted strings also i am getting 3 pipelines 

SQL> select regexp_substr('100|||200||300|||400||||0','(\|*\d.*?)\|{3}|(\|*\d$)',1,3) from dual;

REGEXP
------
400|||

 I am new to regular expressions , Pls do favour

Comment: select regexp_substr('100|||200||300|||400||||0','(\|*\d.*?)\|{3}|(\|*\d$)',1,3,null,1) from dual;

Comment: Thank You So much :) Working perfectly